# Gas fee limit issue when deploying smart contract to Optimistic Ethereum

Tags: remix, gas-limit

I firstly apologise if I am asking something stupid. I am a newbie to smart contract development (and this is my first time to ask a question).

I would like to get more familiar with gas fee consumption. So I wrote a short transaction contract like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract ethDeposit {
    
    struct information {
        string[] dataList;
        uint totalValue;
    }
    mapping (address => information) transactionInfo;
    mapping (address => uint64) transactionCount;


    event transactionLog(address sendAddress, address receiveAddress, string transactionData, uint transactionValue);

    function logStorage (address payable receiver, string memory data) payable external {
        receiver.transfer(msg.value);
        emit transactionLog(msg.sender, receiver, data, msg.value);
    }


}
```

I am using Remix IDE currently. I could deploy it on JavaVM and the Ropsten test network. However, when I try to deploy the contract on Optimistic Ethereum, I got the following error and stating Gas Estimation Failed:

```
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "gas required exceeds allowance (125000000)" }
```

I did enable the Optimistic Ethereum plugin for Remix IDE. Majority of the related issue on Google are due to coding issue, but I doubt if this is the issue here as I could deploy the contract smoothly on other networks.

If I force the transaction to continue, it then returns the following error:

```
creation of ethDeposit errored: Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"code":-32000,"message":"L2 gas limit too low: 0, use at least 100000"}}}'
```

I did set the gas limit to 3000000 in Remix IDE. Did I do the whole deployment process wrongly for Optimistic Ethereum? Or is there some other way I should declared Layer 2 gas limit?

I followed this tutorial for Remix Optimistic Ethereum plugin, but I still get the same errors if I use the sample code mentioned in the tutorial. (https://remix-optimism-compiler-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Is there anyone encountered this issue before? Any hint and help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying contracts on Optimistic Ethereum is still in the whitelist stage, not for the public.